# How to enable custom ordering on a list?

Tags: 2007, list, list-view, object-model

I want to be able to create a list programmatically which allows end users to reorder the items in the list. There appear to be 2 steps to this. Firstly set the SPList.Ordered property to true - this bit seems easy enough. The second step would seem to be to set the default view's OrderedView to be true. Unfortunately this field is readonly. I see you can set this value if you provision through CAML but I want to be able to set this after the fact in code. Does anybody know how to do this? You can see the funcitonality I'm after by creating a Links list. Then in the Actions menu you get the option to "Change Order".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not create a new list based on the Links list type?

Answer (score 1):

I remember having to do this in SP2003, the only solution that worked was to create a list based upon the links list template, and modifying the list as required.